# Monogame/XNA: Colors not displayed correctly. Weird blending and different almost each execution

Tags: c#, colors, xna, monogame, blending

I tried searching for this problem several hours and did not find any solution.
Here it goes:
I started programming a small Pokemon-like RPG with fights including healthbars.

For the healthbars I'm using this code:

```cs
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle((int)hpBarPosition.X - 2, (int)hpBarPosition.Y - 2, monstar.HPBase + 4, hpBarHeight + 4), Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle((int)hpBarPosition.X, (int)hpBarPosition.Y, monstar.HPCurrent, hpBarHeight), Color.Green);
}
```

Relevant variables are explained here:

- `monstar.HPBase` and `HPCurrent` are just int values like 300.
- `hpBarPosition` is initialized `Vector2 hpBarPosition = new Vector2(350, 180);`
- `hpBarHeight` is 10.
- `pixel` is initialized in the constructor of my HPBar class as
  `pixel = new Texture2D(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);`
- The `spriteBatch` is the same as in my main class. (its just passed as parameter)
- The `Draw`-Method is called in the `Draw`-Method of the main class between a `GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Indigo); spriteBatch.Begin();` and a `spriteBatch.End();`

Btw my class does NOT inherit from `DrawableGameComponent`. Im just calling my self-written `Draw` methods in the draw method in the main class.

Now I expected a black bar with a slightly smaller green bar on top of it so that the black bar acts as a border to the green bar. However the black color is not showing up AT ALL. And the green bar is a mix between Green and Indigo, which is a dark blueish green similar to CadetBlue on [this chart](http://www.kyleschouviller.com/files/xnacolors/xnacolors.html). But its not always like that. Sometimes i get the black bar and a very dark green on it and very very rarely it looks as intended.

I'm using the newest Monogame version on Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7. And apart from the healthbar, all other textures like characters, monsters, backgroundtiles are displayed properly.

Any idea what the problem is?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your texture isn't being properly initialized?  Try using pixel.SetData() to set it to pure white after you create it.

Comment: Wow. That worked! I thought it will default to White anyways so i dont need to touch it further. 
Thanks alot !
So if it wasnt White with 255 Alpha, what was it then?

Comment: Probably random garbage, which would explain it being different every time you ran it.